# variable error in makefile

Tags: makefile

`I have Makefile in Ubuntu12.10 as below`.
when I run it by make command, it shows as 
   g++    -c -o myprog1.o myprog1.cpp

It seems the variables CFLAGS and CINCLUDE do not work.

Can any one help me to check it?

Thanks,

---

```
RM  = rm -f
CC  = gcc
AR  = ar rc

CFLAGS= -Wall -g -O2 -std=c++11 -fPIC 
CINCLUDE= -I. -I../include
OBJECTS= myprog1.o myprog2.o  

STATIC_LIB = libctest.a

$(STATIC_LIB): $(OBJECTS)
$(AR) $(STATIC_LIB) $(OBJECTS) 

%.o : %.c
$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CINCLUDE) $< -o $@

clean:
$(RM) $(OBJECTS)
$(RM) $(STATIC_LIB)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a make rule for `%.o : %.c` but not for `%.o : %.cpp`.  When you run the make, the [implicit make rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) for '%.cpp' runs, but the implicit rule doesn't contain references to `CFLAGS` or `CINCLUDE`.

Since your source is in c++, you probably want to add another rule for c++ compilation and set up the `CXX` variables appropriately.

```
CXXFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)

%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(CINCLUDE) $< -o $@
```